# Error connecting to wifi with bcm43217 and wpa_supplicant

Tags: wpa-supplicant, broadcom, android-firmware

I was trying to make an old lying around Huawei B310-927s a Wi-Fi-to-Lan bridge. First, I tried connecting to a Wi-Fi with wl(broadcom proprietary driver) but I couldn't get it to work, I found out it uses an android based kernel and uses an ARM processor, so next I downloaded static wpa_supplicant and wpa_cli from [this](https://github.com/drygdryg/wifi_tools_static/releases) github repo and moved them to my router. But when I try running wpa_supplicant, it gives an error that it failed to initialize nl80211. The router does not have that driver in the kernel. But it does have the wl driver, I can verify that using the lsmod command:

```
root@p711:/app/lib # lsmod
snd_soc_balong 183128 4 - Live 0xbf64c000 (O)
wl 6133393 0 - Live 0xbf017000 (PO)
ctf 26352 0 - Live 0xbf004000 (PO)
```

wpa_supplicant errror:

```
/var/wpa_supplicant -c /var/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wl0 -Dwl
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wl0: Unsupported driver 'wl'
```

So how can I make wpa_supplicant work?

I am new in linux and c, so please bear with me.

I tried using the wl command line utility and wpa_supplicant.

Also: I used the precompiled binaries from the github repo. in the wpa_supplicant help message, it only shows nl80211 as a possible driver. I don't know how to make it see the wl driver.

Comment: Off topic and wrong site. Belongs at Superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com